# Do the authors of Star Trek Expanded Universe books attempt to stay consistent with each other?

Tags: star-trek, canon, star-trek-eu

To what extent do the main authors of Star Trek EU novels (Peter David, Kieth R. A. Candido, etc) attempt to maintain some level of "consistency" with each other? Do they keep track of each others works (or use Memory Alpha/Beta) to make sure they don't step on each other's toes? Or is it a free-for-all, with anyone just writing anything at any time? Or some mixture of the two?

Comment: I don't read the books, but I know friends have told me there are inconsistencies between them.  That's 2nd hand and I don't know how serious those inconsistencies are.

Comment: Most of these books were written *well* before the public had the Internet, let alone Memory Alpha or Beta.

Answer (score 4):

If you have read many of the novels you will realize that the answer is no effort whatsoever.  Probably the only thing in common is the name of the ship and the main characters.  Anything else goes.