# What is this Nicholas Cage movie?

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I'm sure Nicholas Cage is in this movie. He has a daughter, but the daughters mother (I think) was sucked into a book (hundreds of years in the past) and can't speak and is being held in a castle as a kitchen helper. Something like that. That's all I can remember. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you remember when you watched it? Maybe any other details? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if it'll help you add in a few more details

Answer (score 12):

It's a Brendan Fraser movie, and it sounds very much like [Inkheart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_(film)).

Based on the book of the same name, it follows Mortimer "Mo" Folchart and his daughter Meggie, and Mo has the power to read people into books, and fictional characters out of them.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Damn I thought it was this, but don't remember the plot well enough.

Comment: @Apeltree: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: How do you confuse Nick Cage with Brendan Fraser?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I could imagine it's much easier to confuse Nicholas Cage with [Paul Bettany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Bettany), as he's in the film as well.