# Book series about vampires, shape shifters

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, urban-fantasy, shape-shifter

I remember reading a book series where the books were set in the same universe. There was some kind of threat coming and there were some people with special powers who would be able to stop it. They possibly shot something blue out of their hands (not sure about this).

One of the books I clearly remember is there is shape shifter royal family who's son could choose anything to shape shift into until a certain age when he must choose a single animal and there is this girl who is a shape shifting jaguar (I think, but it was surely some feline animal) and at the end of the book, there is a shape shifting dragon and a fight and the royal boy chooses the jaguar as his choice of one animal.

The whole series was basically identifying these special people and uniting them. There were witches, vampires. One other book in the series had a vampire hunter, one other book had a witch who had that special power etc.

Comment: Where and when did you read it. Do you remember the format, paperback, hardback, eBook?  This meta thread has some good advice for more points to include. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178952/fantasy-novel-with-boy-who-can-shapeshift-into-a-jaguar sounds similar.

Comment: Did you read this in English?

Answer (score 2):

This is the 'Night World' series by L.J.Smith. the book with the jaguar is the last one currently published; 'Witchlight'.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_World